# Custom validation Page_Validators[i].isvalid always come as true

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

guys I am using javascript to modify css of control which contain invalid data using asp.net serverside validations but when I use Regular experession validation it come as true and class isnot applied to the control when data is invalid. Also it works on a control when it contains data if control is empty it doesnot work.Also when I leave textbox empty where regular expression is used or both regular expression and required field is used textbox border  color remains same ie it doesnt change to red.

my page is like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        .ErrorControl
        {
            background-color: #FBE3E4;
            border: solid 1px Red;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
    runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression ="^[1-9]\d*$" ControlToValidate ="TextBox2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid data"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    </div>
    </form>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           function Validate(sender, args) {
               if (document.getElementById(sender.controltovalidate).value != "") {
                   args.IsValid = true;
               } else {
                   args.IsValid = false;
               }
           }
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
        if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {
            for (var i in Page_Validators) {
                try {
                    var control = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
                    alert(i);
                    alert(Page_Validators[i].isvalid);
                    if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                        control.className = "ErrorControl";
                    } else {
                        control.className = "";
                    }
                } catch (e) { }
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegularExpressionValidator`s don't check for empty strings - they leave that to the `RequiredFieldValidator`.

When you have both validators, the `RequiredFieldValidator` will set the `className="ErrorControl"` but then the `RegularExpressionValidator` will reset it to `className=""`. This is why it is not changing border color.

One fairly clean and simple way around this would be to remove all `ErrorControl` classes from the form before you check the validators, then just add it for invalid ones:

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
    if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {

        // find and remove all .ErrorControl classes
        var errorControls = document.querySelectorAll('.ErrorControl');
        for (var ec = 0; ec < errorControls.length; ec++) {
            errorControls[ec].className = "";
        }

        for (var i in Page_Validators) {
            try {
                var control = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
                alert(i);
                alert(Page_Validators[i].isvalid);
                if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                    control.className = "ErrorControl";
                } // no need to remove ErrorControl if valid
            } catch (e) { }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```